# Где на сайте можно поздравить членов сообщества с Новым годом?

Tags: предложение, поздравление

Какой бы научный сайт ни был, но ведь человеческий фактор всегда на первом месте! Мне очень нравится доброжелательный и эмоциональный стиль Галины Аванесовой, хотя кто-то и делал ей замечания... Предлагаю отвести специальное место для поздравлений, чтобы его видели сразу все участники,но чтоб он не нарушал научных дискуссий.

А пока его нет, разрешите всех поздравить с Новым годом! Всем здоровья, успехов в овладении русским языком, удач во всех начинаниях и простого человеческого счастья! И с наступающим   7 527 годом, который наступит в марте! И мои вирши как  творческий комментарий.

Год Парящего Орла

К  душе всему миру  восточный уклад ,

Мы  все, знать,  китайской породы.

Какая нам разница, что  за зверь,  гад

Бал  правит в течение года?

Кто же нам, кто,  в  каковы времена

Китайский всучил  гороскоп?

А была наша Русь велика и сильна,

У славян  был свой  Летослов.

Водолея  эпоха набирает разгон,

Под звездою Сварога был русич рождён.

И тотем наш на весь предстоящий год-

Сам Парящий Орёл – нам  сказал  так  Сварог.

И сдаёт уж бразды Свернувшийся Ёж,

Орёл  ведь совсем  уже рядом…

И против него уже не пойдёшь –

Всё будет по древним обрядам.

Сбирает  Ёж в поредевший мешок

Неудачи, болезнь и тревогу –

Всё   будет  у нас, друзья,  хорошо -

Потерпите – осталось немного.

Парит наш Орел где-то там в вышине,

Среди  белизны  облаков,

В небесной нашей   кружит синеве,

Под взором  славянских  богов!

Пускай же уверенно  машут крыла,

И  ясен  будь  взгляд  прозорливых  очей,

Раскрытая даль  будь  добра и  светла!

Сиянья всем  солнечных дней!

Answer (score 1):

Людмила, спасибо вам за поздравления! С праздником (пусть уже прошедшим)!

Поздравления, наверно, можно оформить в таком виде, как это сделали вы, но вообще, обычно мы создавали отдельные страницы для них. В этом году она будет чуть-чуть позже :)